# In Java how can I simply retrieve the Keys from a mongo document?

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, key

I understand that MongoDB is a "schemaless" database, but it seems strange (and frustrating) that I can't replicate this mongo query in Java:

```
Object.keys(db.appnOffer.findOne());
```

I have tried to pull a `keySet` into an array and iterate through it, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because MongoDB is schemaless (although it is more correct to say that it has a flexible schmema from an applications point of view), this can't work reliably. Consider a document like this

```js
{
  _id: new ObjectId(),
  lastname: "Bar",
  firstname: "Foo",
  phones:[
    {type: "work", number: "+1 234 567890"},
    {type: "mobile", number: "+1 555 000000"}
  ]
}
```

Now, we have no problem until we get to `phones`. Now, what should be considered as key here: `phones` or `type` or `number`? And if we took phones, how should the embedded documents be deserialized?

Furthermore, since some documents may be missing data (because you added fields to your model) it might get unnoticed when a field is missing.

Since you are using Java, I suggest you iterate over your [entity classes' declared fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()) instead.

That being said: [DBCollection.findOne() returns a DBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#findOne--), which [inherits the keySet() method of BSONObject](https://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/org/bson/BSONObject.html#keySet()). This method returns a `Set<String>` over which you can iterate as follows:

```java
DBObject obj = collection.findOne();
Set<String> keys = obj.keySet();
Iterator iterator = keys.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()){
  String key = iterator.next();
  Object value = obj.get(key);
  /* Do whatever you want */
}
```

Comment: I did add that in and tweak it to perform the required action.  of course I get something back that makes no sense to me:

'
Usage : [--bucket bucketname] action
  where  action is one of:
      list                      : lists all files in the store
      put filename              : puts the file filename into the store
      get filename1 filename2   : gets filename1 from store and sends to filename2
      md5 filename              : does an md5 hash on a file in the db (for testing)'

I get this type of thing all the time and have no idea what it refers to.

Comment: @CLStegall Please add the complete code of the method in question and the stack trace.

Comment: I discovered it was a setting within my Eclipse program.  All good now! Thanks much!

Comment: @CLStegall Feel free to upvote or accept the answer, then ;)